# how to make a vector of different values in R for linear regression

Tags: r

I have a matrix (data1) looking like:

```
 gene       S869      S907       S909   S016          S090         S160
1 S1          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
2 S2          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
3 S3          0          0          0   0.423405          0          0
4 S4          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
5 S5          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
6 S6          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
```

I have another dataset (data2) looking like:

```
Cultivar  Dose
S869  10
S907  5
S909  7
S016  19
S090  15
S160  12
```

Then I want to do a linear regression using

```
for (gene in 1:ngenes){
model = lm(Dose~X[gene,])
}
```

I want to check regression between genes and dose using these two datasets. So that I get p values for all genes for dose across all varieties. Thank you in advance!

Comment: is `data1` matrix or data.frame.  I am assuming that it is `data.frame` because `matrix` can have only a single class

Comment: it's a data.frame.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `X[,gene]`? The current `X[gene,]` is trying to select rows, whereas I think you need a column.

Comment: I want to select rows i.e., genes across all varieties for dose. To see which genes have significant p values for the dose across all varieties.

Comment: Typically (always?), a regression needs exactly as many response values (`Dose`) as there are dependent variables (`data1` column). I don't know that a regression of just one value will be useful.

Comment: Thank you! That's why I want to do a regression using genes. May be can add dose as a row in data1 to use. I am not sure about the best way.

Comment: @akrun, Thank you! I checked it. For regression, it is still using dose w.r.t variety, right? I think the output I am looking for is e.g., genes S1 (p value -----) for dose across all varieties so that I can see which genes are important for this dose.

Comment: So, you need a single `lm` instead of multiple?  You have mutiple 'Dose' values?

Comment: I need multiple lm for all genes not varieties. Sorry if I was not clear before. I do not have multiple Dose levels for same Dose. But I have different kind of Dose that I want to check one by one. May be can make Data1 with all such different Doses and do multiple lm for all genes w.r.t. to each different Dose at one time. But the different Dose have NA values for different varieties for each Dose.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` to loop over the 'Cultivar, 'Dose' column, create a 'Dose' column in 'data1' subset based on the 'Cultivar' column and apply `lm`

```
Map(function(x, y) lm(Dose ~ ., transform(data1[x], Dose = y)), 
          as.character(data2$Cultivar), data2$Dose)
```

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(gene = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"), 
    S869 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S907 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), S909 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S016 = c(0, 0, 
    0.423405, 0, 0, 0), S090 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S160 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

data2 <- structure(list(Cultivar = c("S869", "S907", "S909", "S016", "S090", 
"S160"), Dose = c(10L, 5L, 7L, 19L, 15L, 12L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```